# Degree of field extension using minimal polynomials

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

My notes say that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3}): \mathbb{Q}]$ equals 6.

How is this so?  We have

$[\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3}): \mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})][\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}]= \deg(m_{\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})}(\omega)) \cdot \deg(m_{\mathbb{Q}}(2^{1/3}))=\deg(x^3 -1)\cdot \deg(x^3-2) = 9 $

?

Comment: Does $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

$\deg(m_{\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})}(\omega))=\color{red}2 ,$  since $\omega^2+\omega+1=0.$

Comment: How did you work out that equals zero?

Comment: This is a given. It's a convention to denote non-real roots $1$ by $\omega$. Without this convention the starting statement is meaningless since we don't know what $\omega$ is.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you were using common notation with $\omega^3=1$ and $\omega\ne1$, since you didn't otherwise define $\omega$